# How to parse date and time with milliseconds, spread across multiple columns?

Tags: r, posixct, posixlt

I am having issues with incorporating milliseconds in formatting date and time which has milliseconds.

Description:
date format in csv is spread across first 3 columns  2014/12/22,14:48:51,800 as date, time and milliseconds , respectively. 
So, I essentially merge them into 1. Here, for illustration I have taken 1 row of the dataframe

```
temp
#[1] "2014/12/22" "14:48:51"   "800" 

temp <- gsub("/","-",paste(temp[1],paste(temp[2],temp[3],sep="."),sep=" "))
#[1] "2014-12-22 14:48:51.800"
```

then, set the options

```
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
options(op)
Date_time <- as.POSIXlt(strptime(temp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))
#[1] "2014-12-22 14:48:51.8 IST"
```

output of the above would give me "2014-12-22 15:10:41.8 IST" . **But, for milliseconds 8 and 80 also it gives the same output "2014-12-22 15:10:41.8 IST"**

Also, if I use format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3" I get NA.

Comment: Thanks Akrun for prompt reply!. with sprintf for 80 milliseconds I am getting "2014-12-22 14:48:51.008 IST" and for 800 "2014-12-22 14:48:51.08 IST" . I presume we need some more modification. 


Reply to first comment : for 80 milliseconds  3 columns in csv are "2014/12/22,14:48:51,080"

Comment: Expected output:  Posix time is desired  which would ideally be 
"2014-12-22 14:48:51.008" for 8 milliseconds "2014-12-22 14:48:51.080" for 80 and "2014-12-22 14:48:51.800" for 800

Comment: I posted my comment as a solution.  It gives what you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` to paste the columns together as it is easier to modify the format of the 'millisec' column with `sprintf`.  Then, convert to datetime class with `strptime`.

```
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
strptime(sprintf("%s %s.%03d", temp[,1], temp[,2], 
          temp[,3]), format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS')
#[1] "2014-12-22 14:48:51.800 IST" "2014-12-22 14:48:51.008 IST" 
#[3] "2014-12-22 14:48:51.080 IST"
```

#### data

```
temp <- structure(list(date = c("2014/12/22", "2014/12/22",
    "2014/12/22"), time = c("14:48:51", "14:48:51", "14:48:51"),
   millisec = c(800L, 8L, 80L)), .Names = c("date", 
  "time", "millisec"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Was trying out the solution provided by Akrun but still it fails. Code is as follows:
temp <- strsplit(x="2014/12/22,14:48:51,800",split=",")
temp <- unlist(temp)
temp1 <- temp[1]
temp2 <- temp[2]
temp3 <- as.integer(temp[3])
temp <- sprintf("%s %s.%03d", temp1, temp2, temp3)
temp
#[1] "2014/12/22 14:48:51.800"
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
strptime(temp, format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS')
# "2014-12-22 14:48:51.8 IST"

Comment: @rahulkmishra  You are only using a single row element.  Have you tried using the example data I showed?

Comment: @rahulkmishra  When there is only element as you showed, it just prints with the `.8`.  But, is that a big issue?  If you need this for printing, you can use `format` i.e. `format(strptime(temp, format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3')
#[1] "2014-12-22 14:48:51.800"`

Comment: I tried with your example now and it works like a charm. But any idea where would I be going wrong. Does it really depend on the data structure ? Shouldn't the  logic work even for single row? And I even tried on the data.frame but it still eats the zeros at the end. Any suspicion?

Comment: @rahulkmishra Also, the 8 milliseconds is printed differently by default, i.e. `strptime(temp2[2], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS')
#[1] "2014-12-22 14:48:51.008 IST"`  So, I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @rahulkmishra  It is only because you have one observation and that has "800" at the end.  When you do the `strptime`, the end zeros are stripped off..  By using `format`, it can be restored for printing purpose.

Comment: Cool . I get it !! Thanks! For printing I am using format now